# Houghlines not detecting top line of a simple rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, houghlines

I'm stumped.  It's a simple white rectangle on a black background.  Houghlines can't find the top line.  It can find all the others, just not the top.

Anyone?

https://www.screencast.com/t/bNu4sptcS3a

Comment: Try increasing `rho` or thickening the lines first by dilating the image with `cv2.dilate()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the top edge appears on the result of canny edge detection.
2. Dilate the image to make the edge fatter, so that it can get more votes
3. Make sure that the resolution of parameter rho is 1, so that the detector dos not miss the line. See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) for a description on parameters.
4. Decrease the threshold value for voting, just in case. While the top and bottom lines are supposed to get equal number of votes, this might be different in practice.

The value of rho should be lower for the top horizontal line than the bottom horizontal line.